# ValueError on pandas.DataFrame.pivot example

Tags: python, pivot, valueerror

I am trying to pivot a dataframe in my code and got a value error "ValueError: Length of passed values is 153900, index implies 2". in attempt to solve the problem I copied the pandas example at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html and it gives the same error

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
       "lev1": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       "lev2": [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
       "lev3": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
       "lev4": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       "values": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df.pivot(index=["lev1", "lev2"], columns=["lev3"],values="values")
```

which gives:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-ecb7df0ae99b> in <module>
----> 1 df.pivot(index=["lev1", "lev2"], columns=["lev3"],values="values")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
   5192         """
   5193         from pandas.core.reshape.reshape import pivot
-> 5194         return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
   5195 
   5196     _shared_docs['pivot_table'] = """

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
    412         else:
    413             indexed = self._constructor_sliced(self[values].values,
--> 414                                                index=index)
    415     return indexed.unstack(columns)
    416 

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
        260                             'Length of passed values is {val}, '
        261                             'index implies {ind}'
    --> 262                             .format(val=len(data), ind=len(index)))
        263                 except TypeError:
        264                     pass
    
    ValueError: Length of passed values is 6, index implies 2
```

Could it be a python version issue? I am running python 3.7.1 in JupyterLab in an Anaconda setup.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of pandas, the specifications may have changed since 1.0.0.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have been the problem. The environment that I was working in was using a very old (0.23.4) version of padas.